# How to send an email by php and xampp localhost?

Tags: xampp, php-7

i have a problem on my server side file

i tried to send an email but i did find nothing in the mail box

```
<?
$from = 'faresbenslama95@gmail.com';
$to_email = 'faresbenslama95@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Testing PHP Mail';
$message = 'This mail is sent using the PHP mail function';
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1" . "\r\n";
mail('faresbenslama95@gmail.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

i expect to receive the email but no message received.

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss the  php on propose at the beginning  or just yo show the example. The code seems fine